# Show client date/time in ASP.net repeater, value stored in UTC

Tags: asp.net, timezone, repeater

I have a LINQ to Entities query and loading up a ASP Repeater with a list of files and when they were uploaded. They are showing UTC date/time but I need it to display the client time.

```
var files = db.Files
              .Where(f => f.IsAvailable == true && f.IsArchived == showTeamArchived && f.FileTypeID == 1 && f.ProjectID == projectid)
              .Select(f => new { f.ProjectID, f.UserID, f.FolderID, FileName = f.FileName.Replace(".sqlite", ""), FileID = f.FileID, f.AspNetUser.Email, f.DateCreated, f.LastUpdated, Status = f.IsArchived == true ? "Archived" : "" });
```

f.LastUpdated is the date I'm trying to format.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTeamFiles" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%#Eval("LastUpdated")%></td>
                                            ....
```

Comment: You haven't posted any ASP.NET code or how you display that data. That's where formatting is applied. It could be a format string on whatever element you use to display that date, or it could be a crude `<%@=thatDate.ToString("...")%>`

Comment: If by "the client time" you mean you need to convert it to the time zone of the end user visiting your web site, you'll either need to know in your server-side code what time zone the client is in, or you'll need to send the UTC time to the client in some other manner and convert it in the browser using JavaScript.  (Lots of questions already on S.O. about both approaches...)

Comment: I know I need to do it using JavaScript but not sure where to call the script. I'm already sending the UTC time to the client but how do you convert it in the repeater??

Comment: A repeater is a *server-side* control.  Use "view source" in your browser and you'll see what it generates.  You'll likely want script outside of the repeater, and place some other html (a div, etc.) inside the repeater such that you end up with lots of divs and can run your script against the right one.  There are lots of other questions on StackOverflow already about generating and running JavaScript from within an ASP.Net control such as a repeater (and others).  I suggest trying a simple one first (perhaps by itself instead of in a repeater), and then expand from there.  Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this when the OnPreRender event gets fired for the repeater. Using the Moment-Timezone javascripts, I loop through the spans with a specific class and convert the date/time to the users local timezone.

ASP.Net

```
protected void rptTeamFiles_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "localtime" + dtCount++, "<script>showLocalDateTime();</script>", false);
    }
```

Javascript

```
function showLocalDateTime() {

        var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        var l = spans.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var spanClass = spans[i].getAttribute("class");
            if (spanClass == "localdatetime") {
                var utc = moment.tz(spans[i].innerHTML, "UTC");
                var local = utc.clone().tz(moment.tz.guess());
                spans[i].innerHTML = local.format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');

            }
        }
    }
```